# Split string by whitespace

Tags: ruby

I would like to split a string by whitespace sequences.

For example this string: `"\tFirst \t\tSecond    Third \t"` should be an array like this: `['First', 'Second', 'Third']`

Unfortunately `@array = str.split(' ')` or `str.split('\t')` doesn't work in this case.

Comment: I think you should accept @steenslag's answer instead of mine. But it's your call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String#split` can accept a regex ([documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/String.html#method-i-split))

```
s = "\tFirst \t\tSecond Third \t"

s.split(/\s/).reject(&:empty?) # => ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

Comment: @ChrisHeald: it would, indeed.

Answer (score 14):

Do nothing, just split. Whitespace is the default!

```
p "\tFirst \t\tSecond Third \t".split # => ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```

Comment: Exactly right.  Per the Ruby [`String#split` documentation](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split): "if pattern is omitted... str is split on whitespace".

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@array = str.split(/\s/)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `String#scan`.

```
"\tFirst \t\tSecond Third \t".scan(/\w+/) # => ["First", "Second", "Third"]
```